# how to use ssdt hook tech to intercept the operations of creating new folders?

Tags: hook, driver

I hooked native api **ZwCreateFile**, and wdk doc says windows use **ZwCreateFile** to create or open a directory. I can detect the operation of opening testdir, but i failed to stop the open directory operation.
My code of my own **FakeZwCreateFile** like this：

```
NTSTATUS FakeZwOpenFile(
    OUT PHANDLE  FileHandle,
    IN ACCESS_MASK  DesiredAccess,
    IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES  ObjectAttributes,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK  IoStatusBlock,
    IN ULONG  ShareAccess,
    IN ULONG  OpenOptions
    )
{
    NTSTATUS rtStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    UNICODE_STRING test = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\??\\c:\\testdir");

    if (!RtlCompareUnicodeString(ObjectAttributes->ObjectName, &test, TRUE))
    {
        DbgPrint("%wZ\n", &test);
        FileHandle = NULL;
        IoStatusBlock->Status = rtStatus = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
        goto exit;
    }

Orig:   
    OrigZwOpenFile = (NTOPENFILE)oldServiceAddr[SYSTEM_INDEX(ZwOpenFile)];
    rtStatus = OrigZwOpenFile(
            FileHandle,
            DesiredAccess,
            ObjectAttributes,
            IoStatusBlock,
            ShareAccess,
            OpenOptions
            );

exit:       
    return rtStatus;
}
```

Why i failed to stop opening the **c:\testdir** directory?? And what shoud i do to intercept the operations of creating new folders????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case is better to use File System Filter Drivers instead of SSDT hooking, Because FS Filter Drivers work correctly in 64Bit version of windows but SSDT only can use in 32Bit (If you can bypass windows Patch Guard then you can use SSDT hook in 32Bit) !